# Twelve Months of Mourning During a Leap Year

Tags: halacha, minhag, calendar, mourning-aveilus, adar

For those who are mourning a parent for the requisite twelve-month aveilus, would Adar 1 and Adar 2 count as two separate months towards the twelve? Or does one year mean a full year, i.e., from Tishrei to Tishrei?

Practically speaking, if one lost a parent on 1 Ellul of last year, can they attend a wedding on 2 Av (except for it being the Nine Days), or must they wait until 2 Ellul?

Comment: I thought that the 11 months is for Kaddish, while the mourning period is a year.

Comment: Oh, that may be true. I'm not an aveil so I'm not too versed in the halachos. If you're sure, I will edit the question.

Comment: @Tzvi - B"H I'm not so well-versed either. I'm sure there's someone around here who is, though.

Comment: Mourning for a parent extends to 12 months (not a year).  Kadish is cut short by a month so as not to imply an assumption that the parent is subject to gehinom (which is 12 months- not a year).  A non-child may be able to say kaddish for 12 months, but has no obligation to say at all.  Yahrtzeit is the only thing dependant on the yearly cycle.

Comment: Actually, that answers the question as well.

Comment: @YDK Go ahead and post an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=450

Per the Nitei Gavriel quoting the Shulchan Aruch there is no difference in a year that has two Adars. The time of mourning is the same length.